# 16bit triangle lists vs 32bit triangle strips

Tags: rendering, performance

When drawing geometry we may use indexed drawing, where we pass index of the vertex we want to draw in array. In this case we need to pick a topology for our geometry and the type of indices.

Popular topologies are triangle lists, where we have to specify 3 indices for each triangle, and triangle strips, where each new triangle shares its first 2 vertices with last 2 vertices of previous triangle.

As for index types - we have 16 bit indices, which allow for ~65k vertices per model, and 32 bit indices, ~4B vertices.

My GPU (1050ti) fetches 32 bit indices at half the rate of 16 bit indices, where 16 bit indices triangle list topology gets it at its maximum throughput, but so do 32bit triangle strips. As my GPU isn't that old, I expect many GPUs to be quite alike in this manner.

So, is the inconvinience of having to specify geometry in strips worse than having a limit to 65k vertices per model?

Comment: "Worse for some games, better for others" is about all we can tell you here, because games' needs vary so widely. What concrete problem have you encountered in *your particular* game that we can help you solve?

Comment: When has software development not been about informed compromises? If you *need* 32 bit indices, they come with a cost. Don't use them if you don't need them. What does your use case suggest?

Comment: Also important to add - half the index rate *does not result in* an end result of half the framerate. Index rate is very unlikely to be a significant contributor to overall performance, so if you need 32-bit indices, use them and optimize later if it's a problem.